# hiding the parameters value in web browser MVC C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

is there a possible way to hide the form data or controllers value in web bowser i need to hide the username and password when logging in im currently working on security for my site.
but unfortunately after checking in google chrome developer's tool every time im requesting for ajax call it shows my password and user name if you go to NETWORK and browse the ajax call. is there s certain code that will hide my sensitive data for me?

Comment: Or should i just encrypt the sensitive data??...
can you provide some codes that could help me out? any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using simple membership? ASP.NET already provide such function

Comment: what do you mean simple membership? im currently using VS2012 express edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no effective way to hide the username and password from the browser, if the attacker has access to the browser then the war is lost. What you should do however is protect it during transit from the user's browser to your server. You can accomplish this by using SSL. SSL will encrypt the form data in transmission so someone intercepting the traffic cannot view the form data.

Setting up SSL is beyond the scope of SO so here's a link to get you started.
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

You can ask more questions on how to setup SSL in the Superusers stackexchange site.

Comment: +1 i think this solution is the best but i dont have budget could you give me some other option like form encryption? i think certificate is expensive??

Comment: I don't think certs are all that expensive, but if you just need one for testing or something you can use a self-signed certificate:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx  Only problem is the browser will probably generate warnings so might not be good enough for production.

Comment: Startcom provides free SSL certificates that are recognized on major browsers. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSL_certificates_for_web_servers.